# Balm of the Summer Court fey energy dice usage limits

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, druid

If I'm a level 5 druid ([Circle of Dreams](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/druid#CircleofDreams), from *Xanathar's Guide to Everything*).  Am I limited to using two fey energy dice for my Balm of the Summer Court feature before having to take a long rest to use it again?

Comment: Welcome! You can take the [tour] as an introduction to the site and check the [help] if you need further guidance. Good luck and happy gaming!

Answer (score 20):

## You're limited to two dice *per use*, but five dice per long rest

There's rules in the feature about only using half your dice, but not in the context of a long rest:

> At 2nd level, you become imbued with the blessings of the Summer Court. You are a font of energy that offers respite from injuries. You have a pool of fey energy represented by **a number of d6s equal to your druid level.**
>
> As a bonus action, you can choose one creature you can see within 120 feet of you and **spend** a number of those dice equal to **half your druid level or less**. [...]
>
> You regain all **expended dice** when you finish a long rest.
>
> —**Balm of the Summer Court**, Xanathar's Guide to Everything, pg. 22

So at level 5, the druid would be permitted to spend 2.5 dice per use, which we round down to 2 because of the general rule about rounding:

> There's one more general rule you need to know at the outset. Whenever you divide a number in the game, round down if you end up with a fraction, even if the fraction is one-half or greater.
>
> —**Round Down**, Player's Handbook, pg. 7

So between Long Rests, a Druid could use this feature five times, spending 1 die each time, or three times with 2 dice for the first two and 1 for the last, or any other permutation they choose that obeys these restrictions.

Comment: Dammit you beat me to it.

Comment: Technically there's no need for any rounding in this case. You can leave it as "spend up to 2.5 dice", since the only numbers of dice less than or equal to 2.5 are 1 and 2. In this case the rounding rule gives you the same answer, so you could argue it's splitting semantic hairs, but even if the rounding rule said to round up, I would say this rule still limits a 5th level druid to 2 dice at a time.

Comment: @RyanThompson What you said makes no sense. Of course you have to round the number because you can't use half a die. Therefore you can only round it to 2 or 3 and since there is a rule for it the number would be 2 or fewer in this case. In your comment by saying it would be 1 or 2 or even 3 as you said it is still rounding to a whole number.

Answer (score 2):

### No

You currently have a pool of 5 d6s that you can use to heal people. Once you use all 5 you will need to take a long rest to use them again.

However, as a bonus action, you can only use a maximum of 2 of these dice. But that will still leave you with at least 3 to use before you need to take a long rest.

Comment: You've got the bones of a good answer here, but supporting it with rules citations would get my upvote :)

Comment: I recommend not calling them "hit dice", since that's a different concept in DnD 5e.